# Displacement on single vertex inside of a mesh

Tags: displacement, audio, fcurves

I am currently trying to make individual joints (vertexes) on a human figure move based on an audio file. I've done this for objects in the past for nonspecific movement by using a displacement modifier and keying the strength then baking the audio to f-curves. For this project, I want to move the joints of this figure based on audio, but have different joints react to different aspects of the audio. I thought having each vertex have its own displacement with different F-curve modifiers would work, but the displacement only works on the entire model, not just one point. This might not be the best way to do what I am looking to do, I'm fairly new to blender so apologies if there is something obvious I am missing!

Summary of desired outcome: be able to have each joint (vertex) move based on an audio track, but have different displacement settings and different f-curve modifications.

Thanks for any help! [image: The skeleton under the mesh]

Comment: You can set each vertex to its own vertex group and create a displace modifier for each different vertex group

Comment: @Gorgious Thank you for your reply! So I would make a vertex group for each point and have the same number of displacement modifiers each one with a different group specified in that setting?

Comment: Yup, you can set the target VG in the modifier there https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2uXx.png

Comment: @Gorgious Perfect works like a charm! Thank you